# How can I deserialize an array of objects in Symfony Serializer?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

Is is possible in `Symfony Serializer` to deserialize an array of objects in a property? I have a `Boss` class with the `$Npc = []` property that needs to hold a array of `Npc` objects. I did see some examples in the documentation, but they do not state this feature.  I have a json string with an array of NPC's For example:

```
class Boss {

    private $Npc = [];    

    /**
    * @return Npc[]
    */
    public function getNpcs(): array
    {
        return $this->npcs;
    }
}
```

I am using php7.1 and symfony/serializer version ^3.3.

Edit:
I already tried PhpDocExtractor, but it would not let me install it. :(

Edit:
This is a possible JSON value:

```
{
    "bossname": "Epic boss!",
    "npcs": [{
        "id": 24723,
        "name": "Selin Fireheart",
        "urlSlug": "selin-fireheart",
        "creatureDisplayId": 22642
    }]
}
```

Comment: Damn it ! I'm sorry I modified your question instead of my answer. I added the 'use statement'

Comment: @db306 haha, that was not what I ment though. See my answer.

Answer (score 16):

I found a way to do this :). I installed the Symfony PropertyAccess package through Composer. With this package, you can add adders, removers and hassers. This way Symfony Serializer will automaticly fill the array with the correct objects.
Example:

```
private $npcs = [];

public function addNpc(Npc $npc): void
{
    $this->npcs[] = $npc;
}

public function hasNpcs(): bool
{
    return count($this->npcs) > 0
}
```

etc.

This way you can use the ObjectNormalizer with:

```
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor());
```

---

**Edit**: At least since v3.4 you have to create a remover method as well. Otherwise it just won't work (no error or warning).

Comment: At least for v3.4, you **have** to set also a remover for this to work (I lost a couple of hours debuggin this). Make sure to check your plurials.

Comment: I also needed to add setter method for the property `setNpcs()` on v5. As a note, even if you define `addNpc` and `hasNpcs` methods,  they are not actually called. `Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\ReflectionExtractor::getMutatorMethod()` will check if those methods exist and `Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\ReflectionExtractor::extractFromReflectionType()` finds argument class name defined for you `addNpc()` method

Answer (score 8):

I have struggled with this many hours without getting a result.
Every time i added an adder function, the objectnormalizer wanted to invoke this function but got an error something like "The field xyz should be of type xyz[], array given".

This is cause i forgot to add the `ArrayDenormalizer` to the normalizer pool of the serializer. After adding this, everything worked fine.

Hope this is helpful for somebody.

Comment: what is "arraynormalizer"?

Comment: I found, need `ArrayDenormalizer`, apply my edit request pls.

Answer (score 8):

The following (full) example is working for me with Symfony 5.3 components. It combines some of the above and adds some more necessary parts:

The Serializer needs to include `ArrayDenormalizer` as well as `ObjectNormalizer`. The `ObjectNormalizer` needs proper configuration. The full creation can look like this:

```php
return new Serializer(
    [
        new ArrayDenormalizer(),
        new DateTimeNormalizer(),
        new ObjectNormalizer(
            null,
            null,
            null,
            new ReflectionExtractor()
        ),
    ],
    [
        new JsonEncoder(),
    ]
);
```

It seems like order is important regarding the normalizer / denormalizer, probably due to priority. Placing `DateTimeNormalizer` after `ObjectNormalizer` won't work.

The target class needs to provide three methods in order to allow mapping of an array of other classes:

```php
class Place
{
    /**
     * @var OpeningHour[]
     */
    protected $openingHours = [];

    /**
     * @return OpeningHour[]
     */
    public function getOpeningHoursSpecification(): array
    {
        return $this->openingHours;
    }

    public function addOpeningHoursSpecification(OpeningHour $openingHour): void
    {
        $this->openingHours[] = $openingHour;
    }

    public function removeOpeningHoursSpecification(OpeningHour $openingHour): void
    {
    }
}
```

All three methods need to exist. The first in order to allow Serializer to fetch existing values and allow comparison. The other two need to exist in order to adapt existing value to match expected one by adding missing and removing no longer existing entities.

The above does not provide implementation for removal as this is taken from a one way project.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can deserialize the array but you need to provide on the second parameter the object as well as the information that it is in fact an array. You can do this like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

class Boss {

    private $Npc = [];    

    /**
    * @return Npc[]
    */
    public function getNpcs(): array
    {
        return $serializer->deserialize($this->npcs, 'Acme\Npc[]', 'json');

    }
}
```

You can find more information about this in the documentation on [handling arrays](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-arrays)

Comment: That deserialized the json to a array of objects. But I want to deserialize to the Npc property (see the first post).

Comment: Your question was "Is is possible in Symfony Serializer to deserialize an array of objects in a property?" So you want it the other way round ? What do you want: your object to hold an array of objects or a serialized json representing an array of objects ?

Comment: See my second edit: I want to deserialize those npc objects from the JSON to the npc property of the Boss class as a Npc class.

Comment: It currently deserialized as a normal array. But I want to deserialize it as a Npc array

Comment: In order to be a Npc array you need an Npc Class

Comment: Yes, I know. I have a Npc class. But how do I let the serializer deserialize that into the array as Npc objects?

Comment: just change 'YourNameSpace\Boss[]' for 'YourNameSpace\Npc[]' Then you will be telling serializer, hey it's a Npc class !

Comment: Why? That does not make sense. I never used Boss[]. It is a single boss with a Npc property that needs to filled with Npc Objects. But is deserializes as a normal array instead of npd objects.

Comment: You have a JSON serialized array of of Npc objects. You want to deserialize that array into Npc objects, which is logic because its an array of Npc objects. Right? Then you need to tell Serializer that it's an array of Npc objects. You do this by telling him : `$serializer->deserialize($this->npcs, 'Acme\Npc[]', 'json');`

Comment: Yea, That is right, but I want to deserialize a Boss object. How do I automatically let the serializer also deserialize the npc objects? If I use that, it would not make a boss object.

Comment: Then just deserialize your boss object: `$boss = $serializer->deserialize($your_json, Boss::class, 'json');` then when you do this `$boss->getNpcs()` it will deserialize the Npcs array of Npc objects

Comment: I assume you have the right structure than when you serialized this boss object otherwise you are trying to hydrate an object that doesn't fit the proper structure and thus will just not work the way you intend to

Comment: Thanks for the patience, I think I am way overthinking it. I am now deserializer the npc objects separately and setting them in the boss object.

Comment: @mikeRovers I think that should be the way to go :) In any case, in terms of your question and how its formulated that was the answer to the original question :) Thanks for ur rating