# How to solve exception NotNormalizableValueException during deserialization array of objects in Serializer Component?

Tags: symfony

The following error occurs during object deserialization:

> *Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\NotNormalizableValueException*
>
> The type of the "products" attribute for class "shop\manage\flexbe\objects\Lead" must be one of "shop\manage\flexbe\objects\Product[]" ("array" given).

Have JSON-object:

```
{
  "id": "9757241",
  "time": "1567105530",
  // other params
  "products": [
    {
    "title": "Product name",
    "count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

In the Lead class that describes the object related methods to "products":

```
private $products = [];

/**
 * @return Product[]
 */
public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->products;
}

/**
 * @param Product $product
*/
public function addProduct(Product $product): void
{
    $this->products[] = $product;
}
```

Deserialization Code:

```
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, new PropertyAccessor(), new ReflectionExtractor());
$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array(new JsonEncoder()));
$lead =  $serializer->deserialize($data, Lead::class, 'json');
```

I can’t understand what the problem is. It is expected using the addProduct() method  deserializer should bypass the array and add all objects to Product class like [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273427/how-can-i-deserialize-an-array-of-objects-in-symfony-serializer).

Answer (score 0):

I decided using an ArrayDenormalizer, and a setter with PHPDoc indicating the data type, an array of Products [] objects. But why the method with addProduct () did not work - the question remains.

Deserialization:

```
$encoder = [new JsonEncoder()];
$extractor = new PropertyInfoExtractor([], [new ReflectionExtractor()]);
$normalizer = [new ArrayDenormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, $extractor)];
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizer, $encoder);
/** @var $lead Lead  */
$lead = $serializer->deserialize($data,Lead::class,'json');
```

Setter for products in the Lead class:

```
/**
* @param Product[] $products
*/
public function setProducts(array $products)
{
$this->products = $products;
}
```